# Android App Architecture: Using LiveData + Flow and Coroutines

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I have app implemented based on this google sample project using LiveData 
https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/17c315a050745c61ae8e79000bc0251305bd148b/GithubBrowserSample

It worked fine

Now I am implementing new Android app and I know there are Kotlin Coroutines and Flow 
I've found here google sample reimplemented using Flow I think 
https://github.com/juanmendez/android-architecture-components/blob/repo-with-coroutine-flows/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/api/GithubService.kt

My general question is whether should I migrate in new project to this Coroutines and Flow in Service, DataSource, Repositories, etc. Maybe also ViewModel or stay with LiveData.

It seems like LiveData are getting a bit deprecated from Google I/O especially taking into account Compose, and Coroutines.

It seems Flow and Coroutines are executed async, and LiveData on the main thread?  Google Sample project as I remember used Executors to put api and database calls into background thread.

Comment: I would like to comment on this line: "LiveData are getting a bit deprecated". No it's not, because `LiveData` has something that `Flow` can't provide in Android Development. It's `Lifecycle` aware component for Activity/Fragment.

Comment: Yes but I understand I should migrate all code from Repository, Dao, Service (Retrofit) into closures and just map this closures to LiveData in ViewModel

Comment: Yep, that would be doable in my opinion.